# Hive Subquery with Group By

Tags: hive

I'm new to Hive but consider myself intermediate at SQL. I'm getting the error shown below. I've tried changing, adding, removing parentheses and their locations as well as adding & removing subquery aliases. Nothing seems to clear the error. Your help is appreciated!

```
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: 
FAILED: ParseException line 16:11 missing ) at 'testing' near ')' in expression specification
```

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS batting;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS batting(id STRING, year INT, team STRING, league STRING, games INT, ab INT, runs INT, hits INT, doubles INT, triples INT, homeruns INT, rbi INT, sb INT, cs INT, walks INT, strikeouts INT, ibb INT, hbp INT, sh INT, sf INT, gidp INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/user/maria_dev/hivetest/batting';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS master;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS master(id STRING, byear INT, bmonth INT, bday INT, bcountry STRING, bstate STRING, bcity STRING, dyear INT, dmonth INT, dday INT, dcountry STRING, dstate STRING, dcity STRING, fname STRING, lname STRING, name STRING, weight INT, height INT, bats STRING, throws STRING, debut STRING, finalgame STRING, retro STRING, bbref STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/user/maria_dev/hivetest/master';


SELECT
bcity, bstate
FROM( 
    SELECT bcity, bstate, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total_double_triples DESC) as ranked 
        FROM 
        ( SELECT  bcity, bstate, SUM(doubles+triples) as total_double_triples 
            FROM
            (
                ((SELECT id as b_id, doubles, triples 
                    FROM batting) batting_data 
                JOIN 
                (SELECT id, bcity, bstate 
                    FROM master 
                    WHERE NOT ISNULL(bcity) AND NOT ISNULL(bstate)) master_join
                    ON master_join.id = batting_data.b_id)
         ) testing GROUP BY (bcity, bstat)
        ) total_group_by  
    ) subquery 
WHERE subquery.ranked <= 5
;
```

Comment: I think you just need to add one more `)` after `ON master_join.id = batting_data.b_id)`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks for the suggestion. However, all my parenthesis are properly closed. Do I need to add an additional opening parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

Missing SELECT in the subquery and extra (). See comments marked `-- 1st, 2nd and 3rd` in the code:

```
SELECT bcity, bstate FROM( 
    SELECT bcity, bstate, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total_double_triples DESC) as ranked 
        FROM 
        ( SELECT  bcity, bstate, SUM(doubles+triples) as total_double_triples 
            FROM
            (--There should be SELECT ... FROM ---------------------------------- 1st 
                ( ----------Remove this line ------------------------------------ 2nd
                  (SELECT id as b_id, doubles, triples 
                    FROM batting) batting_data 
                JOIN 
                (SELECT id, bcity, bstate 
                    FROM master 
                    WHERE NOT ISNULL(bcity) AND NOT ISNULL(bstate)
                ) master_join
                    ON master_join.id = batting_data.b_id ) --Remove extra)------3rd
            ) testing GROUP BY (bcity, bstat)
        ) total_group_by  
    ) subquery  WHERE subquery.ranked <= 5 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to remove the alias prior to the Group By statement as well as fix a type in bstate field name. Thanks to all that proposed solutions!

```
SELECT bcity, bstate FROM( 
    SELECT bcity, bstate, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY total_double_triples DESC) as ranked FROM ( 
        SELECT  bcity, bstate, SUM(doubles+triples) as total_double_triples FROM (
               (SELECT id as b_id, doubles, triples FROM batting) batting_data 
                JOIN 
               (SELECT id, bcity, bstate FROM master WHERE NOT ISNULL(bcity) AND NOT ISNULL(bstate)) master_join
                    ON master_join.id = batting_data.b_id  
            )  GROUP BY bcity, bstate
        )  group_by_totals 
    ) subquery  WHERE subquery.ranked <= 5 ;
```